# Checkbox's - Application Crashes on startup

Tags: android, checkbox

I was following this sample http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/checkbox-ui/android-checkbox-example/ to add checkbox's to my add but every time I add `addListenerOnChkWindows();` and `addListenerOnButton();` the application crashes on startup. Heres my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
    private static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";
    private boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
    private Button shareButton;
     private CheckBox linux, macos, windows;

       private Button button;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
addListenerOnChkWindows();
addListenerOnButton();
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        sendNotification(mTitle.toString());
        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility

        ) 

        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Posted();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment =  new Settings();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new About();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /**
     * Send a notification message
     */
    //public void sendNotification(String title) {

        //String content = "Tap to share";
        //NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            //  this).setContentTitle(title).setContentText(content)
            //  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setAutoCancel(false).setOngoing(true);
    /// NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    //  Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    //  TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    //  stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        //stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    //  PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        ///        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
        ////            0,
        //            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        //        );
        //Builder mBuilder = null;
        //mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        //nMgr.notify(1, builder.build());
        //
    //}

    public void sendNotification(String title) {
        String content = "Tap to share";
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
        this).setContentTitle(title).setContentText(content)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setAutoCancel(false).setOngoing(true);
        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your application to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
     public void addListenerOnChkWindows() {

            windows = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.shareButton);

            windows.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {

                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Bro, try Linux :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

              }
            });

          }

          public void addListenerOnButton() {

            linux = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.fb);
            macos = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.tt);
            windows = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.tr);
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shareButton);

            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {

                StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
                result.append("Linux check : ").append(linux.isChecked());
                result.append("\nMac OS check : ").append(macos.isChecked());
                result.append("\nWindows check :").append(windows.isChecked());

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              }
            });

          }

}
```

The code for the checkbox is at the very bottom

Here's the stack trace: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B98htuh05n20eXBiN3p6MTBHVHM/view?usp=sharing

And heres my XML

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.openshareproo.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
            android:id="@+id/shareButton"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/share" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fb"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fb" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_tt" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/tt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/View01"
        android:text="Tap to Share"
        android:checked="true"
 />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view1"
        android:text="Tap to Share" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/tr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/View01"
        android:text="Tap to Share"
 />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Web"
        android:onClick="buttonMe" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fb"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Twitter"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="35dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:text="Facebook"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="35dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/View01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/View01"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:text="Tumblr"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="35dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_tr" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Well a few things are faulty on a first look: you should use setOnCheckListener instead of the set on click listener in the check boxes. You are using the same variable windows and assigning two different ids to it. In any case please post the stack trace

Comment: I removed OnChkWindows from my build. Still, the activity crashes ans the error from the Logcat/Stack trace is the same

Answer (score 1):

A stack trace would be useful to answer your question.
However, I'm willing to bet the problem is in your xml layout you defined `shareButton` as a `Button`, while in your code in the addListenerOnChkWindows() you cast it to `CheckBox`. You probably wanted to use `R.id.tr` instead of `R.id.shareButton` in that method?

Update:
In `addListenerOnChkWindows()` change the line:

windows = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.shareButton);

to:

windows = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.tr);

Comment: I added a stack trace there

Comment: My XML seems to match my java. Will I include XML?

Comment: There I added the XML, would it help if I moved the checkbox code to a seperate class?

Comment: I tried your method and didnt seem to work. I even tried removing the addListenerOnChkWindows and vice versa with addListenerOnButton();

Comment: From your XML I'm exactly right about what is causing the crash. It's possible there are other problems as well, but after doing what I described you will fix the bug causing the crash from your stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks for helping but the stack trace only seems to point to me it can't launch the activity. Will I post a new stack trace?

Comment: Your stacktrace says:
"Caused by NullPointerException:
...addListenerOnChkWindows(MainActivity.java:313"
You have to look down the stacktrace, at the cause of the exception not at the very top of the stacktrace.

Comment: I found what you were talking about but it doesn't explain why the application is crashing

Comment: You are casting a Button to a Checkbox... that's why it is crashing! What is not clear?

Comment: If it was to change r.id.shareButton to r.I'd.tr that's already corrected

Comment: You made the change, but you're getting the crash in the same exact place? With the same stacktrace crashing on the same line?

Comment: I don't know if it was on the exact line the crash occurs, it is happening in the same place but is also occurring in the public void addListenerOnButton()